# No wireless mobile connection to computer as simulator. Error 10060

Tags: flutter, adb

```
ADB-QR: cannot connect to 192.168.1.104:42663: 
A connection attempt failed because the connected party   
did not properly respond after a period of time, or   
established connection failed because connected host  
has failed to respond. (10060)
```

[image]

[image]

usb debugging ON
wireless debugging ON
Install via USB ON

Comment: Your question is a bit sparse, usually you should first describe what you are trying to do and describe your set-up. Not just post the error message. Are you sure the IP is correct and phone access via IP is not blocked by a firewall? Also please do not post console output as screen shot (first image). Just copy and paste it as text and format it as code.

Comment: @Milad Edalatian describe what you are trying to achieve and paste code instead of images